# How to delete already import certificate/alias by keytool command?

Tags: java, ssl, keytool

I am trying to delete already import certificate by keytool command

```
 keytool -delete -noprompt -alias "initcert" -keystore keycloak.jks
```

But getting below exception

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist:
>   keycloak.jks

Same issue with

```
keytool -delete  -alias "initcert" -keystore keycloak.cer
```

issue

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist:
>   keycloak.cer

Now i am trying to import the certificate with same alias  name

```
 keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias "initcert" -file "C:\Code_Base\keycloak_certificates\keycloak_135.250.138.74_server\keycloak.cer" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

But again end with

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias
>    already exists

Comment: You try to delete the certificate from `keycloak.jks` but tries to Import it in `cacerts`?

Comment: is `keycloak.cer` or `keycloak.jks` in actual working Directory?

Comment: keycloak.cer/keycloak.jks  is certificate name

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make use of **KeyStore Explorer** to check if exists and manage your certs easily,

[KeyStore Explorer Download Link](http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html)

Just **open your keystore file** with the explorer, do the stuff you want and save it back.

Comment: useful open source GUI tool for the Java command-line utilities keytool and jarsigner

Answer (score 52):

It seems you didn't write the full keystore path. The command should be like  this:

```
keytool -delete -noprompt -alias "initcert" -keystore "C:\Path\to\your\keystore\keycloak.jks"
```

About the last error, as other pointed out, "cacerts" is different keystore than your keycloak where you have already imported your certificate. You can check if your alias is in there by using the following command:

```
keytool -list -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

And to delete it:

```
keytool -delete -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias "initcert" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

Then, if you import again the certificate, the error would not appear.

Finally, one last thing, if there is an error like this

> keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Path\to\your\keystore\keycloak.jks (Permission denied)

You should execute the command window in Administrator mode.

Comment: Thanks @mardo but i am that directory only.