# i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - Exception loading JWK from https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks. Micronaut Java

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-client

I am using the Asp.net core Identity server for OAuth with Micronaut 2.5.6 application as below configuration

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: feteBirdService
  server:
    port: 8085
    cors:
      enabled: true
  security:
    enabled: true
    token:
      jwt:
        enabled: true
        signatures:
          jwks:
            IdentityServer:
              url: 'https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks'
```

I am using Mac OS, the JWK from the browser

```
{"keys":[{"kty":"RSA","use":"sig","kid":"A144FFAF7B9CCEB98368A0D2242C08B8","e":"AQAB","n":"6S4cvwbYF9KvRwpD98y3LgX0Ca9YVba62Lp6e2H0SyTTa3xcH-eLeUCZ3bAIXTcEMKXEuynmXS0KTtDjM1OFHgsaExMknkGxn3lsRzOeWCXOFoWYY_6hecE2PtCqGrHqD1RVwpf5eCBfvLBzJa0mrPNffgBm-xQ7hoesuaFKe1qGiW28ORDqltgKBNyyw9b1RjVDuUiliqguRgbfr-MDEzXLt_i7-PEhDx7277XXPrGbZlfl0tJIk8c9sfFsqtKlySBCiFXN1_vnCo-vx2xsAcRlmMDzw34_-yWp73kvEa9QmJFWSza1PE_1nggel-k0znEiKXQxw1FEekgXT-btvQ","alg":"RS256"}]}
```

**Exception**

```
20:42:15.032 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-7] ERROR i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - Exception loading JWK from https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks. The JwksSignature will not be used to verify a JWT if further refresh attempts fail
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1498)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1404)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:441)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:412)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:574)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1653)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1577)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.DefaultResourceRetriever.getInputStream(DefaultResourceRetriever.java:305)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.util.DefaultResourceRetriever.retrieveResource(DefaultResourceRetriever.java:257)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet.load(JWKSet.java:508)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet.load(JWKSet.java:472)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet.load(JWKSet.java:527)
    at io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.JwksSignature.loadJwkSet(JwksSignature.java:166)
    at io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.JwksSignature.getJWKSet(JwksSignature.java:95)
    at io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.JwksSignature.verify(JwksSignature.java:145)
    at io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.validator.JwtValidator.validate(JwtValidator.java:218)
    at io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.validator.JwtValidator.validate(JwtValidator.java:134)
    at io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.validator.JwtValidator.validate(JwtValidator.java:85)
    at io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.validator.JwtValidator.validate(JwtValidator.java:71)
    at io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.validator.JwtTokenValidator.validateToken(JwtTokenValidator.java:79)
    at io.micronaut.security.token.validator.TokenValidator.validateToken(TokenValidator.java:54)
    at io.micronaut.security.token.TokenAuthenticationFetcher.lambda$fetchAuthentication$0(TokenAuthenticationFetcher.java:81)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFlatMap.java:132)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onNext(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:59)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$IteratorSubscription.slowPath(FlowableFromIterable.java:236)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$BaseRangeSubscription.request(FlowableFromIterable.java:124)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableFlatMap.java:117)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onSubscribe(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:52)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribe(FlowableFromIterable.java:69)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribeActual(FlowableFromIterable.java:47)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:57)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMap.java:53)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableElementAtMaybe.subscribeActual(FlowableElementAtMaybe.java:36)
    at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:4290)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedMaybe.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedMaybe.java:53)
    at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:4290)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeMap.subscribeActual(MaybeMap.java:40)
    at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:4290)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeToFlowable.subscribeActual(MaybeToFlowable.java:45)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFlatMap.java:163)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onNext(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:59)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$IteratorSubscription.slowPath(FlowableFromIterable.java:236)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$BaseRangeSubscription.request(FlowableFromIterable.java:124)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableFlatMap.java:117)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedSubscriber.onSubscribe(RxInstrumentedSubscriber.java:52)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribe(FlowableFromIterable.java:69)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribeActual(FlowableFromIterable.java:47)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:57)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMap.java:53)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableElementAtMaybe.subscribeActual(FlowableElementAtMaybe.java:36)
    at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:4290)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedMaybe.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedMaybe.java:53)
    at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:4290)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeDoOnEvent.subscribeActual(MaybeDoOnEvent.java:39)
    at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:4290)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeToFlowable.subscribeActual(MaybeToFlowable.java:45)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMap.java:53)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.subscribeActual(FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.java:32)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14868)
    at io.micronaut.tracing.brave.instrument.http.HttpServerTracingPublisher.subscribe(HttpServerTracingPublisher.java:85)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.Publishers.lambda$map$3(Publishers.java:205)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.executeRoute(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1120)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.handleRouteMatch(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:776)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:607)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:149)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:200)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:123)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.dequeue(FlowControlHandler.java:200)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.channelRead(FlowControlHandler.java:162)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 147 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 152 common frames omitted
```

Keychain

[image]

I tried the below 2 solutions

1. Update the java to latest version
2. import the certificate using the below command

Solution from here [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)

```
sudo keytool -–importcert -file /PathTo/YourCertFileDownloadedFromBrowserLockIcon.crt -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -alias "Cert" -storepass changeit
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the cetificate from Browser or export for keychain
Well this solve my issue

```
sudo keytool -–importcert -file /Users/macbook/Desktop/localhost.cer -keystore /Users/macbook/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-16.0.1/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

List the keychains

```
keytool -list -keystore /Users/san/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.2/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
```

If the above command doesn't work then

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias localhost -file /Users/san/Desktop/localhost.cer -keystore /Users/san/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.2/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

The path for the java sdk should be the same as the IDE is using

[image]

If you want to delete then follow this [How to delete already import certificate/alias by keytool command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204014/how-to-delete-already-import-certificate-alias-by-keytool-command)